# setObject:forKey: mutating method sent to immutable object

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutabledictionary

What am I missing...?

elsewhere in my project there is code like this:

```
let allUsers = ["userName":["difficulty": 1, "highscore": 50],"userName2":["difficulty": 2, "highscore: 75]]          
defaults.setObject(allUsers, forKey: "allUsers")
```

I want to change a value for one user in that array of users:

```
var allUsers = defaults.objectForKey("allUsers") as! [String:NSMutableDictionary]

let changingUser = allUsers["userName"]! as NSMutableDictionary
```

Neither of these will work:

```
changingUser.setObject(3, forKey: "difficulty")
changingUser["difficulty"] = 3
```

with the error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

Comment: The objects returned from `objectForKey` will be immutable. You can't simply downcast an immutable dictionary to a mutable dictionary. You need to create a new NSMutableArray from the array returned from user defaults, modify that and then write it back.

Comment: You could also type your allUsers dictionary initially, such as `let allUsers: [String:NSMutableDictionary] = ...`.  Your cast to NSMutableDictionary would be correct at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just cast a `NSDictionary` to a `NSMutableDictionary`. You can initialize one by passing in an immutable counterpart, but unfortunately that isn't a deep mutable structure.

However, you *can* cast it to a Swift Dictionary and assign it to a var:

```
var allUsers = defaults.objectForKey("allUsers") as? [String: [String: Int]] ?? [:]
allUsers2["userName"]?["difficulty"] = 3
```

But note that Swift dictionaries are value objects and have value semantics. That is, if you do this in steps like so:

```
var allUsers = defaults.objectForKey("allUsers") as? [String: [String: Int]] ?? [:]
changingUser = allUsers["userName"]
changingUser?["difficulty"] = 3 //mutates a copy
```

This will not work, since `changingUser` is a copy and while writing to it, does mutate it, it doesn't mutate the `allUsers` dictionary. So you have to either write the changed inner dict back into the outer dict, or do as I did above.

Comment: So it checks whether allUsers is a [String: [String: Int]] and if not then [:] does what? just sets it to an array of AnyObjects? In my case, it will always be [String: [String: Int]]. Thank you!

Comment: No, the type system guarantees that a given variable (or constant) always has s consistent type. So the ?? part is a default value of the cast fails, that returns an empty dictionary, but still of type `[String: [String: Int]]`